# How do you publish your meteor application to the web?

Tags: meteor

So, in the documentation, it describes in full detail, in multiple places how you can publish your app to meteor.com, but what about it if you want to publish it to your own server, as I'm sure most people want to do... How do you do that?

You describe basically how to do it here:

Install Meteor:

$ curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
Create a project:

$ meteor create myapp
Run it locally:

$ cd myapp
$ meteor
=> Meteor server running on: http://[thisis]localhost:3000/ <- stackoverflow made me do that
Unleash it on the world (on a free server we provide):

$ meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com

But that deploys it to meteor.com, and as I said, I would like to publish it to my own server, and then make different apps, as I think your framework is pretty amazing!

So, could you please help me out? I'm pretty sure it's obvious that I'm a novice programmer, and something like this to help me get started would go a long way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: a community wiki page describes several ways: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Deployment

Answer (score 4):

Meteor offers [bundling of the app into a deployable file](http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying), which is further down the documentation.

```
meteor bundle myapp.tgz
```

Do that, upload and unpack on your server, and run it making sure that it points to existing mongodb you want to use for it. You might want to change the url and port in this example:

```
PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js
```

Comment: That's awesome, Mark, thank you so much....but just to waste a little bit more of your time....

Is this the only way to do this? It seems kind of complicated...and how will the code be updated to the site?

Also, it says that they provide it as a free service so you can try it. Does that mean they're going to charge in the future?

Sorry, again, crazy newb and in frighteningly unfamiliar territory.

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is the whole deploying by different people to the same domain. If more than one person deploys, won't their code interfere with each others'?

Comment: @ZaneHitchcox As far as I have used Meteor, when injecting "hot-code",  meteor handles it differently. With CSS, it usually just replaces the style elements. For scripts, the page reloads itself. Yes, the code will interfere when more than one person deploys. But isn't that the purpose of source control (GIT, SVN)? Also, meteor's website does offer hosting, but they reserve the right to pull it out eventually.

Comment: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Deployment